# How to apply/distribute customized TFS 2015 web portal to other projects

Tags: tfs, portal, tfs-2015

With the new `TFS` 2015 web portal technology you can customize the appearance of the portal with `WorkItem Query` tiles and specific lists.

For example you have `WorkItem Query` widgets for *Active Tasks*, *Active Bugs*, *New Items* etc. Having done that, we now have a setting that actually makes sense for every project.

Is it possible to distribute this customization to other TeamProjects? How? Currently I see no other way to make the same customization for each and every `TeamProject`.

The TFS installation is on-premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible. No matter customize the tiles or add specific list, all this action are done on the web side. Apparently there are no such settings to meet your requirement on web side.

If you really need this feature, you can submit a feature request in uservoice, it will be kindly reviewed by TFS Administrator Group or PM.

> **UserVoice**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services